# NodeJS + ReactJS: How to make the whole route private?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

In my navigation bar, I have a link called **Categories** that leads to a model **Category**. Only an admin can manage this section (model). I am hiding this link in a view.

But when I access the link directly, like **localhost:3000/categories**, the page will start rendering and then (after approx. 1 second) is the user redirected on the homepage. However - the page will start rendering, so the user can see for a while a content that should be protected.

Here's my (NodeJS) route:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('logged in');
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
    }
    Category.find({}).sort('name').exec(function(err, categories) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(categories));
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's ReactJS component:

```
class Category extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            errors: {},
            categories: []
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('/categories')
            .then(function(response) {
                self.setState({categories: response.data});
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.response.status === 401) {
                    this.props.history.push('/');
                }
                return err;
            })
    }
    ...
```

When an unauthorized user tries to visit **localhost:3000/categories**, NodeJS returns **401** and ReactJS redirects this user on the homepage. However - there's still like 1 second when the user will see loading the protected category page.

I think my approach of solving this situation is not the best (I am new to MERN). The whole route **category** is supposed to be accessible only for the admins.

How do I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using react-router in you react app. If so then for the end point /categories you must be calling Categories component in yyour routes in react. so pass onEnter prop to it and pass a function which will check the session and redirect if user is not authenticated so obviously Categories will never gets called when user is not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add a loading flag, and only show your component content if the Ajax call is done.

```
class Category extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            errors: {},
            categories: [],
            loading: true,
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('/categories')
            .then(function(response) {

                self.setState({
                    categories: response.data,
                    loading: false,
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.response.status === 401) {
                    this.props.history.push('/');
                }
                return err;
            })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div />
        }

        return <ActualComponent />

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent showing Categories when user is not authorized. If you are using react-router then take a look at below solution

```
function redirectIfAuth(nextState, replace) {
    const user = getCurrentUser(store.getState())
    console.log("User state: ", JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
    if (user.get('id')) {
        replace({
            pathname: 'dashboard'
        })
    }else{
       replace({
            pathname: 'login'
        })
    }
}

<Route path="categories" component={Categories}  onEnter={redirectIfAuth}/>
```

Nodejs code:

You can move categories find query to else block and if user not authorized then return relative response inside if block.

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('logged in');
    } else {
        Category.find({}).sort('name').exec(function(err, categories) {
           if(err) throw err;
           res.send(JSON.stringify(categories));
        });
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

And few things I would like to tell you to avoid manual function/object bindings and scope level issues

Start using arrow function so that you can avoid scope issues like let self = this;

```
class Category extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            errors: {},
            categories: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/categories')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({categories: response.data});
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.response.status === 401) {
                    this.props.history.push('/');
                }
                return err;
            })
    }

    handleInputChange = () => {

    }

    handleSubmit = () => {

    }
```